# Why do I have to use in.nextLine(); twice?

Tags: java, string

So in my computer science class I often finish assignments before the due date. In my free time I am creating a basic text rpg to entertain myself. One of the problems I am having that when I try to use the code `response = in.nextLine();` I have to use that line of code twice to get the desired result.

Here is a method from my program.

```
public void room1(){
    System.out.println("The room you are in is empty, I'm not sure how you got in here, I don't write stories. There is one exit to the North. What do you do?");
    System.out.print(">");
    response = in.nextLine();
    response = in.nextLine();
    response = response.toLowerCase();
    if(response.indexOf("go north")>=0){
        move();
        move();
        move();
        room2();
    }

}
```

as you can see I have two lines of repeating code, but in order for me to actually give an input like "Go North" the second line of code has to be there. Why is this the case and how can I make it so I don't have to repeat lines of code?

P.S. The `move();` is because I am using Karel J Robot to function as a player  and map for the game.

Comment: Might want to tag the language (I'm guessing C or C++ looking at the syntax).  This will help you get more views by people that are experienced in the specific language you're looking at.

Comment: @user2366842: Looks more like Java. I've added the java tag; Atticus, please edit if I've guessed incorrectly.

Comment: @KeithThompson it is Java, thank you!

Answer (score 3):

The answer is simple: java.util.Scanner's internal parser methods like `nextInt()`, `nextDouble()` and `next()` don't read parse newline characters.

Take for example, the following input...

```
5 4
three
```

At the beginning, before you have used your Scanner at all, your cursor is placed...

```
|5 4
three
```

...before the 5. Let's say you call `in.nextInt()`...

```
5| 4
three
```

Look at that! The cursor stops *immediately after the 5* because that's where it has finished reading the integer. let's call `in.nextInt()` again...

```
5 4|
three
```

Now it is placed *right after the 4*. Notice that it isn't right before the 3... which is a huge difference. Because the difference between where it is now, and what the following snapshot portrays...

```
5 4
|three
```

...is HUGE. There is a **newline character** between those two cursor points. Now that's what your seemingly mysterious question pokes at... In your case, you probably run into this race condition where you used one of the parsing input methods from Scanner just prior to using `nextLine()` and left a latent newline somewhere, which your first call to `in.nextLine()` consumes, before it consumes the actual input.

So, if we go back to this state...

```
5 4|
three
```

Calling `in.nextLine()` will bring us to...

```
5 4
|three
```

(it consumed everything upto and including the newline, as was present in the buffer... which in this case results in an `""` empty string).

Calling `in.nextLine()` one more time will bring us...

```
5 4
three
|
```

Notice how the cursor isn't at the end of the three, rather it is on the following line, because it consumed everything on the previous line, including the newline character that was present, which results in the string `"three"`.

I loved playing around with this back in the day :). In fact, C++'s `int five, four; cin >> five >> four;` and `string three; getline(cin, three);` behave very similarly to this :), where you'd need an extra `getline(cin, three);` to get rid of that pesky trailing newline :)

Answer (score 0):

The code you posted in itself doesn't contain any issues. I suspect you are reading something (such as an integer) elsewhere which leaves a newline in the input. So the when you call this method, that newline is consumed by the first `nextLine()` call. Hence, it appears to skip one input (or requiring you to have two `nextLine()` calls).

Consider this example:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class temp
{
    public static Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
       while (true) {
          System.out.print("Number:");
          int n = in.nextInt();
          System.out.print("Line1:");
          String r1 = in.nextLine();
          System.out.print("Line2:");
          String r2 = in.nextLine();
          System.out.println("Done "+r1);
          System.out.println("Done "+r2);
       }
    }
}
```

This will always skip the "Line1" input. You probably have the exactly the same problem. You can fix it by having a call to `nextLine()` where you might leave a trailing newline.

Comment: I have edited my code and the problem has been fixed! Thank you for the feedback!

Comment: Is this the problem (newline) or something else?

Comment: I believe this was the problem. I'm not 100% sure to be honest. I added a while loop so if a user gave an input that would not be recognized the need for an input would repeat and something that I changed seemed to fix the problem.

Comment: It's quite easy find. If you read int, double or anything that would leave the newline, then that's it. If you are reading something like that in the said while loop, then that's the issue.

Answer (score 0):

The problem could be what I3x says (elsewhere in the code leaves a new line in the input) because I tried to reproduce the code and it works as expected. You can test it, maybe it will help you.

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        room1();
    }

    public static void room1() {
        System.out.println("The room you are in is empty, I'm not sure how you got in here, I don't write stories. There is one exit to the North. What do you do?");
        System.out.print(">");
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        String response = in.nextLine();
        response = response.toLowerCase();

        if (response.indexOf("go north") >= 0) {
            System.out.println(response);
        }
    }
}
```